# Populate table in java using spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have three entities: `Account`, `Partner`, and `Referral`.

The `Partner` table is already full and has a link to the `Account` table.

When registering a user, the `Account` table is filled out.

Then I need to fill out the `Referral` table in which there are links to the `Account` and the `Partner`.

In this case, I need to check if there is a `Referral` link in the request, I need to check that it is in the `Partner` table and write to the ID `Referral` table of the `Partner`. And also take the ID from the table `Account` and also write it to the `Referral` table.

I have entity and controller

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "partner")
public class Partner implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
private Account account;

@Column(name = "referral_link", nullable = false, unique = true)
@NotEmpty
private String referralLink;

Getter, Setter, and Constructor

@Entity
@Table(name = "referral")
public class Referral implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "partner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "partner_id")
private Set<Partner> partnerId = new HashSet<>();

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private Account accountId;

@Column(name = "device_id")
private String deviceId;

@Column(name = "setup_date", nullable = false)
private Date setupDate;

Getter, Setter, and Constructor
```

In the Controller, I wrote this code:

```
    Long defaultId = 6L;
    if (referralLink == null) {
        referral = new Referral(defaultId, account.getId();
        referralService.create(referral);
    } else {
        List<Partner> partnerList = partnerService.getAll();
        if (partnerList.contains(referralLink)) {
            // How to get partnerId?
            referral = new Referral(partnerId, account.getId();
        } else {
            referral = new Referral(defaultId, account.getId();
            referralService.create(referral);
        }
        referralService.create(referral);
    }
```

Many questions turned out:

- How to get the element's id on the sheet that the `referralLink` belongs to?
- How to add a default ID if the `referralLink` is empty?
- When creating a `Referral`, he asks me for an entity `Account` instead of my `Long` and `Set` partners, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems,

First in your Refferal class

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "partner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "partner_id")
private Set<Partner> partnerId = new HashSet<>();
```

you cannot have JoinColumn at the two sides of the relationship, since this is a bidirectional relation you should have joincolumn in one side and mappedBy in the other side.

In your persistence logic you should have a reference of each side of the relation in the other side since the relation is bidirectional, I am talking about the Refferal and Partner.

> How to get the element's id on the sheet that the referralLink belongs
>   to?

I am not sure what you mean by element's id but I suppose It is entity which has association with Partner, in this case you only need to find the Partner for a specific referralLink and use normal simple getters

> How to add a default ID if the referralLink is empty?

simply check if the referralLink is empty and add an id, if you are talking about the autogeneratedId then why would u need to add such thing and even if you do it will be just ignored, if you are talking about id of another entity (foreign key) set the entity you need if the referralLink.

> When creating a Referral, he asks me for an entity Account instead of
>   my Long and Set partners, what am I doing wrong?

In your referral entity you are specifying not null constraint on the account

```
 @OneToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
 private Account accountId;
```

so just remove "nullable = false"

Comment: So I do not have JoinColumn at the two sides of the relationship. From the referral, table refer to the ID in the partner table

Comment: its a bidirectional relation sho you can refer to any side from the other side

Comment: Thank you, I followed your advice.
Set the default value with "columnDefinition" with referralLink is empty and
remove "nullable = false". But the data in the table Referral is still not written

Comment: check my second note about have reference of each side of the relation to the other